# Excel VBA, Forward and Reverse calculation

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to put a VBA code on my excel sheet such that 2 cells are both input and output of each other depending on which of those 2 cells has been entered last. How can I achieve that? Kindly assist

Answer (score 2):

- Create new Excel workbook
- Open VBA editor (Alt-F11)
- Double-click "Sheet1" on Project pane - its code window will open
- Enter the below code:

```vba
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Static busy As Boolean
If busy Then Exit Sub
busy = True
Select Case Target.Address
    Case "$A$1"
        Range("A2") = "A1=""" & Range("A1").Text & """"
    Case "$A$2"
        Range("A1") = "A2=""" & Range("A1").Text & """"
End Select
busy = False
End Sub
```

- Close VBA editor
- Enter something into cells (manually, copypaste one cell, copypaste range, dragover)
- Look, investigate

Comment: This is awesome Akina. Thank you so much.

Comment: How can I do this for the next pair of cells on the same sheet? If I try to copy and paste the code and adjust the Ranges, I encounter an error message saying "Ambiguous name detected". Kindly assist.

Comment: *for the next pair of cells on the same sheet?* Add next CASE pair into SELECT CASE.